# Add created_at column to migrations table - Laravel

Tags: database, laravel, migration

When we run migrate:install in Laravel framework, migrations table is created in the database that has two columns (migration, batch), there is anyway to add new column which created_at timestamps .
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Update the migrations that you created to add time stamps i.e. `$table->timestamps();` and then run

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

What this will do is, roll back all your migrations and then run them all again. If you also want to follow your refresh by seeding, you should do

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a github project for Laravel 4:

https://github.com/Sano000/laravel-migrate-created_at

I myself will try to port it to Laravel 5.